# What to do if a user insists on mistagging his question?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629536/the-producer-consumer-c is a (rather poor) question on threading issues in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11). The OP however, tagged the question as [c11](/questions/tagged/c11), which is a different language and obviously does not apply to his question. Nice as the community is, it was quickly edited and a friendly and helpful comment was given that notices the difference between the two.

Now the OP has retagged the question again, deleting [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) and putting [c11](/questions/tagged/c11) back to where it was. What to do here without getting into an editing war with the OP? Let him have his incorrect tag?

Comment: I would suggest a nicer tone when pointing to something like that.

Comment: @juergend as I said, *friendly and helpful* ;)

Comment: Posts that end up in a roll-back war are flagged for moderator attention automatically. Step away and let it be.

Comment: If the OP keeps fighting correct edits (e.g. more than two times) flag the question and ask to lock it. This aside, I have flagged couple of offensive comments there. (not yours)

Comment: @MartijnPieters problem is the OP does not roll back (probably unaware of this option) but just making ordinary edit every time, so not sure it will trigger any alarm.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: true, a manual flag would then be appropriate.

Comment: I *think* we still get 'rollback war' flags when the OP is editing in between others' edits, too. Not at all 100% sure on that, but I think I've seen such flags...

Comment: @AndrewBarber question is if it's raised upon sheer amount of rollbacks, or just X rollbacks in a row.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You:

- comment on the question, try to engage the OP. Perhaps try and show that the tag is quite wrong, ask why they insist on changing it. Maybe point to the [editing help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) to explain that collaborative editing is not something to be scared of.
- If the OP keeps rolling back, step back and let a moderator handle it. Repeated rollbacks are automatically flagged for moderator attention.
- If the OP keeps using manual edits to undo changes, flag manually for moderator attention (use the 'Other' option). I'd flag after 3 such reverts, 2 if only one other editor is involved. Step back and let a moderator handle it.

For that specific question, the comments were rather harsh and not constructive, I've flagged some of them on that. 'WTF'-ing someone is not helpful.

Comment: [Yay](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5a1vs.png)!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: WTF? *ahem*